# How do you interpret this variogram?

Tags: spatial, geostatistics, variogram, kriging

Description:

- 8000 spatial data points spanned over an entire state
- 200 bins are used

My question: Is the variogram telling something about the nature of the data? Why is it fluctuating? Should I do additional pre-processing to get better results?

I'm new with kriging and any helps to get me started is appreciated..

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is known as the *hole effect* in the literature. The oscillations correspond to cyclic patterns in your domain. It is very likely that you have "blobs" of high values and low values. The size of these blobs can be read directly off your empirical variogram.

For more information read

*The whole story on the hole effect* by Pyrcz & Deutsch.